# org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed - Bluetooth Earbud Pairing Fail

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

I am trying to pair my JBL earbuds to my pc on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have got 3 exactly same pc, these 3 are exactly same model same brand. When i try to connect my earbud to these two pc, there is no problem. But the other one gives error as below:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 78:5E:A2:75:00:89 
Attempting to pair with 78:5E:A2:75:00:89
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed

[bluetooth]# connect 78:5E:A2:75:00:89 
Attempting to connect to 78:5E:A2:75:00:89
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

And when i open the log file `/var/log/syslog` file is as below, i dont know which part is unnecessary so i just copy the all area related with my device's mac address :

```
Dec 21 12:13:32 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:device_found_callback() hci0 addr 26:CD:23:10:D3:0D, rssi -93 flags 0x0004 eir_len 31
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x5569f9d71ac0: ref=2
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/device.c:bonding_request_new() Requesting bonding for 78:5E:A2:75:00:89
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x5569f9d71ac0: ref=3
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x5569f9d71ac0: ref=2
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:suspend_discovery() 
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:adapter_bonding_attempt() hci0 bdaddr 78:5E:A2:75:00:89 type 0 io_cap 0x04
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:suspend_discovery_complete() status 0x00
Dec 21 12:13:33 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0 type 7 discovering 0 method 0
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:connect_failed_callback() hci0 78:5E:A2:75:00:89 status 4
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: plugins/policy.c:conn_fail_cb() status 4
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 78:5E:A2:75:00:89 type 0 status 0x4
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding 0x5569f9d920e0 status 0x04
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 4
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x5569f9d71ac0: ref=1
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery() 
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:trigger_start_discovery() 
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:cancel_passive_scanning() 
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:pair_device_complete() Connect Failed (0x04)
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 78:5E:A2:75:00:89 type 0 status 0x4
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x04
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 4
Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
```

Sometimes it just connects with one try but 90% it does not. I tried to restart pulseaudio. Problem still occurs. I cant pair my earbud to pc.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your adapter resumes.

> Dec 21 12:13:38 smart bluetoothd[846]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa $HOME/.config/pulse/
```

change

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

to

```
#load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

This I found in [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth_headset#ALSA.2C_bluez5_and_PulseAudio_method)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this. The same error occurs again. Now i am looking the link you attached [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth_headset#Pairing_fails_with_AuthenticationFailed) . The same error is listed there. Maybe it could help. But i think problem is pulseaudio - bluetootctl interaction.

Comment: Did you restart our system?

Comment: yes, actually i am restarting after each try.